# Searching SQLite database inside Android app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I got a searching function inside my app.
It works almost properly, my problem is it is only catching results that similiar to the searchWord from the begining.

For example:
If searchWord is "ada", the results will be contains all the records that START WITH "ada" but not those that contains "ada" somewhere inside them.

I know it must be just a little modification but this is the first piece of database handling i ever did.

So how must i modify this to search for **any contains**, and not for **starts with**?

code:

```
public Cursor getMatchingFromContacts(String searchWord) throws SQLException {

    String queryString = "SELECT _id, full_name FROM "
            + SF_CONTACT_TABLE;

    if (searchWord != null) {
        searchWord = searchWord.trim() + "%";
        queryString += " WHERE " + FULL_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    }
    String params[] = { searchWord };

    if (searchWord == null) {
        params = null;
    }
    try {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString,
                params);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("AutoCompleteDbAdapter", e.toString());
        throw e;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: 1/ understand how what you use works. 2/ extrapolate for expected behaviour. 3/ in doubt read the doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify your block here:

```
if (searchWord != null) {
    searchWord = "%" + searchWord.trim() + "%";
    queryString += " WHERE " + FULL_NAME + " LIKE ?";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
if (searchWord != null) 
{
    searchWord = "%" + searchWord + "%";
    queryString += " WHERE " + FULL_NAME + " LIKE ?";
}
```